# Allow the OP to downvote answers to their question (even with less than 125 Rep)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, downvotes, privileges

Well, the title says everything.

### Why?

I think the OP should, by default, have the right to give *negative* feedback to answers that belong to their question. The OP is most likely the best person to judge such answers so having the ability to downvote incorrect or bad ones shouldn't require any privileges.

We all see new users with comments like:

> No, this is not what I am asking for

A downvote would be more appropriate than such a comment.

I may argue the same for upvotes but this will lead to a lot of abuse and voting fraud so I will stick to only downvotes.

Comment: *A downvote would be more appropriate than such comment.* No. Such a comment expresses in actual words that the targeted answer is  not what the questioner is asking for. It's probably bad form, yes, but it does convey the message. A downvote conveys nothing but the tooltip of the down arrow.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi if the asnwer is not what the OP is asking for then the post is *not useful* (what is written in the downvote arrow). Comments should be used to ask/add clarification. As a side note, I considered a *random* comment to highlight the fact that the OP will express his negative feedback with comments instead of using the downvote feature because he cannot downvote

Comment: As you say, users with 125+ rep are able to do this already, so if I'm not mistaken we are discussing the quasi-fringe case of users who do not have enough rep to downvote an answer and wish to leave a comment without downvoting the answer instead. I'm quite alright with that, especially given the questioner is most probably still learning the ropes, and their input may prove valuable in the long run.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that the OP is the best person to judge such answers. I've seen plenty of cases where it was clearly the correct answer but OP dismissed it because they didn't understand it or it didn't look like what they *think* they wanted. That said, most of the rest of the time I see it happen it's because the OP didn't have enough detail in their question and the answerer was just guessing at what the solution might be, which I definitely wouldn't mind discouraging (but such answers are usually downvoted by other users anyway).

Comment: @John, yep, *comment* is superior to *downvote* even (and especially) if the author of the comment does not understand the answer.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery if an answer doesn't solve OP's problem, then it deserves downvotes, not upvotes. Simple.

Comment: @10Rep I'm not quite sure what part of my comment you're replying to. I never said anything about upvotes.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery when you said "I've seen plenty of cases where it was clearly the correct answer but OP dismissed it because they didn't understand it".

Comment: @10Rep Yes, because as someone who does understand the answer I can see that it actually does solve their problem. That's my entire point, that they aren't necessarily the best judge of whether an answer is correct or not.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery but then why do we let OP's accept one answer? OP might accept a wrong answer

Comment: @10Rep Feel free to take a look at the countless feature requests to not pin accepted answers to the top because of exactly that reason.

Comment: You certainly hit a point there.... but some OP's are experienced people... I'll write an answer.

Comment: One minor(?) thing that hasn't been mentioned here: if OP has only 1 rep, does downvoting an answer still cost 1 rep? :)

Comment: @AndrewT. let's call it the *downvote paradox* ;)

Answer (score 15):

While I think you make a fairly compelling case, I have one counterpoint—and, unfortunately, it's a critical one:

**Users who are new to the Stack Exchange model of Q&A are not the ones we want deciding how our content should be ranked.**

New users don't understand how this site is supposed to work. They don't understand or appreciate how it's unique from the web forums and discussion sites that came before it. They don't understand that votes are a content-rating system, or what the implications of that content rating is.

Lots of users come from social media networks, assuming that an upvote is akin to a "like" button. A downvote button has no counterpart, because on social media, you're rating *people*, not *content* (and you aren't supposed to dislike people, or so they tell me; I don't know much about that world). In fact, my lack of knowledge about how social media sites operate is why I shouldn't be allowed to make decisions about how content is presented or organized there, just as new users' lack of knowledge about how Stack Exchange operates should disqualify them from influencing our ratings.

An answer might be objectively clear and correct, but a new user might decide to downvote it for largely irrelevant reasons, like the person stopped replying to their comments. Or the person has an ugly avatar. Or the person says in their profile that they hate jQuery. Or whatever. This is not useful signal to us.

It's not ideal that new users have to resort to leaving comments to say "thank you" and "this doesn't work for me", but at least the system does allow them to comment on answers to their own questions, even when they don't have full commenting privileges.

And, like others have said, a downvote to say "this doesn't work" is a lot less useful than a comment explaining *why* it doesn't work, which is, I imagine, what anyone who asks a question is going to want to do *anyway*.

Comment: so why allowing the upvote at only 15 Rep (which we can get almost instantly)? Considering your arguments, allowing new users to upvote content is also harmful because we will have *+1 for taking the time to answer me but no this is not what I want*. IMO upvoting bad content is worse than downvoting good one.

Comment: Probably, but that wasn't what you were proposing to change. :-) In all seriousness, I do agree with you—and the logical extension of my own arguments—that the upvoting privilege is set much too low. I imagine that's been discussed before, but I don't remember any specific instances.